# what are the all of the "causes" for an IOerror

Tags: python, exception, io

From Python Docs

> exception IOError
>
> ```
> Raised when an I/O operation (such as a print statement, the built-in open() function or a method of a file object) fails for an
> I/O-related reason, e.g., “file not found” or “disk full”.
> ```

There seems that there is no enumeration of reasons documented on the internet.

IOErrors seem to be place to put exception about io that no other place to live.
I am curious what are all (at least all of the common reasons) for IOErrors.

Lets start with the assumption of access to a file like environment (filesystem that has the concept of files.)
with finite space on it (a hard drive (magnetic media) with 10 Gigabytes).

This question isn't python specific, really, but I need a starting point.

Comment: Just one question. Why do you need it?

Comment: Look through the python source code for `raise IOError`

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'll look at the source.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Python Docs, the `IOError` is an alias of the `OSError`. In other words, the `IOError` is actually the `OSError`, so let's take a look at what the Python docs say about the `OSError`:

> This exception is raised when a system function returns a system-related error, including I/O failures such as “file not found” or “disk full” (not for illegal argument types or other incidental errors).

***Note:** The above statement is true for Python 3.3 and up.*

## Sources:

- Regarding the `IOError` being an alias of the `OSError`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#IOError

***Note:** If you click on the above link, you must scroll up a little to see the text talking about the `IOError` being an alias to the `OSError`.*

- About the OSError: https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError

Answer (score 0):

I/O errors aren't generated by Python, they are from the operating system. Python just parrots the error message passed from the OS.

Comment: Not all the time. For example: I recently found out that PIL will throw an IOError on load when really its more of a decoding error. Granted that's outside the standard library.